# SQL Server: How to call a string with apostrophe in name

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WHERE Variable = 'Lowe's';
```

But string is ending at Lowe because it recognizes the 's as end of String.

How to circumvent this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953257/sql-server-how-to-call-a-string-with-apostrophe-in-name

Comment: @ViniciusLima your second link points to this thread...

Answer (score 4):

Use two `'`

```
WHERE Variable = 'Lowe''s'
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17931)

Answer (score 2):

Although escaping ' with '' works, in case you are running this command from any application you should take a look at databinding and using SqlParameters - spares you a lot of headache, improves performance and security.