# While trying to insert data, It gives me and error specifying that I have a missing comma?

Tags: mysql

```
create table inventory 
(
    Books_number number (8),
    Book_name varchar2 (45), 
    price  number (5),
    quantity number (5)
);

insert into inventory  values (book_seq.nextval*10, 'Midnight Summer's Dream', $5.00, 5);
```

Comment: In general, you have to escape apostrophes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape apostrophe (') in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You have an apostrophe in the book name so it's acting as a delimiter for the string.  Escape that single quote character:

```
insert into inventory values (book_seq.nextval*10, 'Midnight Summer\'s Dream', $5.00, 5);
```