# Escaping single quote in query

Tags: php, sql

My sql query is breaking and throwing

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function result_array()
>   on boolean .

How can i escape the single quote. 
This is my model.

```
function get_ftth_team_by_name($team_name){
    $sql = "SELECT
            *
            FROM
            ct_ftth_teams
            WHERE
            ct_ftth_teams.team_name = '$team_name'";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($result->result_array() as $row) {

        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is my controller.

```
 function add_ftth_team($msg = null)
{

        if (isset($_POST['add_team'])) {
            $data['team_name'] =  $_POST['team_name'];
            $data['team_leader'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['leader_id']);
            $data['team_member'] = $_POST['team_members'];
            $data['description'] = $_POST['description'];

            $get_teams = $this->staff_activity_model->get_ftth_team_by_name($data['team_name']);
            if ($get_teams) {
                redirect('staff_activity/add_ftth_team/error');
            } else {
                $this->staff_activity_model->add_ftth_team($data);
                redirect('staff_activity/view_teams');
            }

        }


        $this->data['main_template'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_main';
        $this->data['inner_template'] = 'staff_activity/ftth/staff_activity_ftth_add_team';
        $this->data['inner_nav'] = 'staff_activity/staff_activity_nav';
        $this->load->view('common/common', $this->data);


}
```

Comment: use prepared statements, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what is there in $result . print_r that

Comment: Your database connection returned FALSE, making it think `$result` is a boolean.  `result_array()`? Never heard of that as a method of a MySQLi result.

Comment: @anish print_r($result) is blank whenever is send post data from form with a single quote . Foreg: if i send team name as Sujan's Team. it is throwing error

Comment: Refer this question,
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql]