# MySQL query issue : WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I recently switched from windows (movamp) to linux (lamp), and i have an issue (syntax error) with a query and i can't figure out why.
Here is the query and the error msg I get:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE trash='false'"
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'false\'' at line 1SELECT * FROM products WHERE trash='false'

I always wrote my queries with that syntax, and i never had problems.

I used to run my code on windows (php 4.1.22 mysql 5.2.11) and used mysql_query() function, and the code worked just fine. 
Now I use(php 7.0.8 - mysql 5.7.16) and use mysqli_query() function to execute queries

Comment: use `mysqli_escape_string` because assigning them

Comment: have you tried without the single quotes? It seems like you trying to escape the single quotes and this is causing the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql

Comment: use `false` if the value is supposed to be string or use just false if the value is supposed to be boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error shows some bogus backslashes that are not present in the query, as if you are actually running this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE trash=\'false\'
```

Not having even a full PHP statement to inspect we can only speculate, and my guess is that —since you are upgrading from a really ancient PHP version— you might be facing some issues with [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). That "feature" no longer exists so nothing in the server can be injecting backslashes automatically so it must be your code the one that's intentionally doing it.

Said that, PHP/4 was superseded by PHP/5 in 2004 (that's like 12 years) and a lot has changed on the way to PHP/7: migration is going to be harder than just dropping the code in the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes , or try reversing the single and double quotes . IF nothing works use a variable with false value.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `trash` ='false'"
```

try this (though your case should also work)

also try to remove the double quotes if you are trying to run SQL query in PHPMYadmin or likes.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you all for your answers and your comments. You helped me figure out what the problem was : the entire query string was beeing escaped instead of only the data tha needed to ne escaped.

I feel dumb  . This was obvious.

Anyway. Thank you a lot for your contibution.