# SQL query error string

Tags: python, mysql, sql, string

in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name="1'-Hydroxyestragole";
```

My query  does not work, because it confuses with the my string that already have a commas in it.

Comment: Try escaping it with another quote, like this: `name="1''-Hydroxyestragole"`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-MySQL for more help on this

Answer (score 1):

You need to `escape the single quote` present `in your string literal`. Try the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name='1''-Hydroxyestragole';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss using the backslash '\' to do the escape character thing.

```
sql_cmd='SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name=\'1\'-Hydroxyestragole\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods:

```
 SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name='1''-Hydroxyestragole';
 SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name='1'+char(39)+'-Hydroxyestragole';
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql=SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name='1''-Hydroxyestragole';

Answer (score 0):

**Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up**

SELECT * FROM ecoprosys.dataset where name='1''-Hydroxyestragole';

Also

In SQL, values should be enclosed within single quote

Example: where name='john' and not name ="john"