# mysql CONCAT keeps escaping

Tags: mysql

Im trying to write a procedure, but in my @qr2  the CONCAT gets escaped when i pass the arg for the substring_index().

Any idea how i can pass the **'-'** into the function, without having it escaping the CONCAT function??

I have tried using "'-'" or \'-\' but nothing works, it keeps escaping it.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE filter_bar (IN bar_state VARCHAR(20), done_state VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
set @qr1 = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', done_state, ' like ', bar_state, ';');
PREPARE smt from @qr1;
EXECUTE smt;
DEALLOCATE smt;

set @qr2 = CONCAT('UPDATE ', bar_state, ' SET date = SUBSTRING_INDEX(date,'-',-1);');
PREPARE smt from @qr2;
EXECUTE smt;
DEALLOCATE smt;

set @qr3 = CONCAT('INSERT into', done_state,'select name, business_id, date, sum(count) as count from', bar_state,' group by name, business_id, date;');
PREPARE smt from @qr3;
EXECUTE smt;
END //
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape apostrophe (') in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql)

Comment: Keep in mind that this opens you up for SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `''`:

```
set @qr2=CONCAT('UPDATE ',bar_state,' SET date=SUBSTRING_INDEX(date,''-'',-1);');
```

You  also need a space:

```
set @qr3 = CONCAT('INSERT into', done_state,' select name, business_id, date, ...'
                                             -- here
```

And finally:

```
DEALLOCATE smt;
=> 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE smt;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c5649ea9830603de9bc5e68d9c74d36)**

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid problems with SQL Injection you should wrap each occurrence of identifier with quoting:

> [The quote_identifier() Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-quote-identifier.html)
>
> Given a string argument, this function produces a quoted identifier suitable for inclusion in SQL statements. This is useful when a value to be used as an identifier is a reserved word or contains backtick (`) characters.

```
bar_state
=>
sys.quote_identifier(bar_state)

done_state
=>
sys.quote_identifier(done_state)
```

Comment: This is prone to SQL injections.