# How to fix syntax error during the insert into table?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, syntax-error

How to correct syntax error when inserting into a table?

```
"Insert Into " . $tableName . " (location_address) Values ('$location_address')"
```

In this code, when the value of the variable has French characters, such as `'`, give an error, I cannot fix it.

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Université, Quebec City, QC, Canada')' at line 1, query was: Insert Into addresses_store_location (location_address) Values ('Université Laval, Pavillon Alphonse-Desjardins, Rue de l'Université, Quebec City, QC, Canada')
```

Who can help me? thanks

Comment: The error is due to the single quote in the `l'Université`, you need to escape the char `'` to `\'` as to fix the issue. Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9596819/2451726)

Comment: Use a prepared statement and bind your values, and you won't have this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before insert your variable in query you should escape quotes:

```
$location_address = addslashes($location_address);
```

You will get the following string:

> l\'Université

Comment: Why not use a prepared statement instead? That would be better... This is not really a good solution to the problem!

Comment: I agree with @Qirel. This is not a good solution. Use prepared statement with bind variables. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to your single quote at `l'université` you can escape it with `\'`

Hope this can help

Comment: I know where the error comes from, but I can't touch the text it comes from another place