# Replacing string contains " \' " with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database where I need to run sql scripts in order to export the new data from a 3rd party. The data then would also need to be cleaned by which I am doing via MySQL workbench.
I am currently stuck at the part where I need to clean the strings containing a combination of a backslash and apostrophe together.

For example,

`June\'s Wedding`

I want the string to be

`June's Wedding`

So first I will be searching for such strings right? So I queried

`SELECT columnname FROM tablename WHERE columnname LIKE '%\\\\''%'`

to see whether my `REPLACE()` will work or not before I proceed to `UPDATE` I change the query to this

`SELECT REPLACE(columnname,'\'','''') FROM tablename WHERE columnname LIKE '%\\\\''%'`

but there is no changes applied to the string as it remains

```
| REPLACE(columnname,'\'','''')|
+------------------------------+
| June\'s Wedding              |
```

How do I resolve this?

Also I am abit confused with the escape characters such as do I need to use the double single-quote `''` in `REPLACE()` or use `\'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**For Update using Double Quote**

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, "\\'s", "") WHERE col1 LIKE "%\\'s%";
```

**For Update using Single Quote**

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, '\\\'s', '') WHERE col1 LIKE '%\\\'s%';
```

Add `\` before the `\` and before `'` if you're going to use single quote for strings.

Check this out [Single Quote, Double Quote, and Backticks in MySQL Queries](https://chartio.com/learn/sql-tips/single-double-quote-and-backticks-in-mysql-queries/)

> If you need to use single quotes and double quotes in a string that contains both a contraction and a quote, you will need to use the backslash ‘' to cancel out the following character. For example: a string containing this ' will recognize the backslash as an instruction to cancel out the single quote’s syntactical meaning and instead insert it into the string as an apostrophe.

And this [How to escape apostrophe (') in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql)

> A `'` inside a string quoted with `'` may be written as `''`.