# Visual studio code: \' (closure for char 39) doesnt work in .mysql file

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I am writing a MySQL's script in Visual Studio Code and it happens that when I've got a string which contains the char: `'` (charcode 39)
and escape it as follow: `\\'`

it is still not interpreted as a character but as a string's closure.

Comment: Have you tried using two single quotes `''` . `SELECT 'Hello''s';`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape apostrophe (') in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql)